# TCP high CPU multiclient server

Tags: c++, sockets

I am curious about best design of TCP server to handle 500+ active connections, that sending a stream of data to me. The biggest problem here is that my data handler uses active CPU and can consume more time than happens between client sending chunks.

Client records a sound with microphone and sends it to my server in real time with chunks of 2000 bytes.

I've written a simple prototype that does next:

1. Listener working and listens for the new connections
2. When new connection happens, it accepts it and dispatches a separate thread to handle this exact connection of stream. It uses poll on socket to get new data.
3. After chunk of data arrives, I am processing it, it can take a long time.
4. After processing of data is done, I am reading next available data from socket and processing it again, and so on till client sends me a special final package.

I believe there's a better design solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the key question to think about is, *what do you want to have happen when data is being sent to your server faster than the server can process it?*

E.g. imagine your server's CPU is fast enough to process 100 audio streams simultaneously in real time, but 200 clients are connected and sending audio.

One way to handle it would be the simple FIFO approach:  only read more data from a given TCP connection when the previously-read data for that connection has already been processed.  That has the advantage that all the data gets processed eventually, but the disadvantage is that if the server isn't calling `recv()` on the socket in a timely manner, then the TCP layer will slow down the TCP connection and the client will no longer be able to send data to the server at the rate the client's microphone is generating it.  (i.e. you've transferred the problem to the client, who now has to decide what to do with the "excess" audio samples it is generating but can't `send()` quickly enough)

Another way would be to have the server buffer the "excess" data in RAM (or on disk); i.e. the server reads all the incoming TCP data as fast as it can and stores it locally somewhere, and then one or more separate threads will process the buffered audio data as quickly as they can.  This has the advantage of not slowing down the network data transmission when the audio-processing tasks can't keep up, but the disadvantage is that if your server is constantly overloaded, the backlog queue will continually get larger and larger until eventually your server runs out of storage space (RAM or disk) and at that point it will likely crash or otherwise become non-operational.

A third approach would be to simply drop some of the excess data, instead of processing it, when the backlog is getting too big (for some appropriate value of "too big").  Whether or not that's a reasonable thing to do depends on your application's use-case.

A fourth approach would be to limit the number of simultaneous clients to a number that you know your server's CPU is powerful enough to handle in a timely manner.  This is the approach used e.g. by most multiplayer-game-servers; then, if you find that your server is "full", you can respond by spinning up a second piece of server hardware.

Regardless of which of the options you choose above, if you don't want your server's audio-processing to slow down the TCP data-transmission, then you'll want to separate your CPU-intensive audio-processing and your `recv()` calls into separate threads, so that your TCP sockets all get `recv()` called on them as quickly as possible.  Otherwise the TCP layer will respond to a temporarily-full-incoming-TCP-buffer by telling the client to slow down his send rate and reduce his TCP packet-window.